# An integral of exponential and algebraic functions

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-transform

I need to do this definite integral,

$$
\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{e^{i \alpha \omega}\omega\sqrt{a - \omega^2}}{e^{b \omega} -1}
$$
Is it possible to do this? Or if I can do the following integral,
$$
\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{e^{i \alpha \omega} \sqrt{a - \omega^2}}{e^{b \omega}-1}
$$
I think I can use differentiation under integration to get the first integral. Are any of these actually doable? I tried the substitution, $\omega = \cos\theta$, but I didn't find it very useful.

Comment: are there any assumptions on $a$, $\alpha$ and $b$?

Comment: a and b are real. $\alpha$ is complex in general. But I will be happy to see if the integral can be done under some assumptions on parameters.

Comment: I guess the square root should be $\sqrt{a^{\color{red}2}-\omega^2}$. In such a case the integral depends on the Fourier series of $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$, i.e. it is a series involving values of a Bessel function, $J_1(n\pi)$.